# unix listing files with the following command

Tags: linux, unix, command

There are four files which are `a`, `aab`, `bb` and `cb`. The command is `ls?[a-b]*`

What is the output ?

```
a. aab bb
b. a aab bb
c. aab bb cb
d. cb
e. a aab bb cb
```

I got `b` as the answer so please confirm if I am right.

Comment: ls ?[a-b]* - is that the command? or is ? supposed to be a space.

Comment: My guess is there's a space before `?`

Comment: http://original.jamesthornton.com/linux/man/glob.7.html

Comment: Hint: mkdir test; cd test; touch a aab bb cb

Comment: Why not just try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: @ShawnChin: we should not really care what your guess is. If you have one, you could rather provide an answer so we can upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

The command in question should be `ls ?[a-b]*` (note the space after `ls`), or else you're likely to end up with a "command not found" error.

Assuming it is indeed`ls ?[a-b]*`, that would mean list files (`ls`) that start with any character (`?`) followed by the letter `a` or `b` (`[a-b]`) followed by anything else or nothing at all (`*`).

This would therefore match files/dirs in the current directory with a name that has **at least 2 letters** with the **second letter being either a or b**.

The answer should therefore be **aab bb cb** (answer C).

P.S. this is actually a pretty nifty trick question which may even trip up some seasoned users, i.e. for globbing, the `*` is a standalone wildcard character and does not act as a modifier to the preceeding  pattern (as in regex).

Comment: `you'll end up with a "command not found"` -> pedantic comment: unless there is a program in the path that has the same name as a file in the current directory matching the pattern `ls ?[a-b]*`, such as e.g. 'lsQab123`. The chance of this happening might rise from the 0.0001‰ to about 0.01‰ iff the PATH variable includes the current directory :). +1 **PS** _my_ guess (!) is that the Regex confusion is actually what tripped the OP. The +1 is for that

Comment: Good point, although from a quick test is seems that command name globbing only works with commands in the current directory and not those within `$PATH`. `0.0001%` doesn't seem so bad ;) Updated post to "likely to end up with...".

Comment: @ Shawn: which is why I explicitly mentioned the PATH requirements ;) (oh and the 'pedantic' tag...)